# Physical properties of cigarette smoke

Tags: ideal-gas

I've been trying to find papers that list various properties of idealized cigarette smoke( ex. the molar mass, gas compressibility factor, density of smoke exiting a cigarette) but I have had very little luck.

Does anyone know what these properties are or where I should be able to find them?

I'm building a volumetric measurement tool for use in psychological studies in case anyone wonders why I'm looking for this information.

I posted this question in chemistry.stackexchange first but I think physics is a better forum for it.

Comment: I imagine it's bit complicated; smoke has a lot of stuff in it, so molar mass is ill-defined. It also has water vapor in it, which condenses to liquid when cooling down to room temperature, which could make compressibility hard to define, and there is a fair amount of solid particulate aerosol matter in it as well. But someone might have a handy reference for what you want. What is a volumetric measurement tool, and how is it being employed in psychological studies?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus we aim to measure cigarette puff volume in order to standardize reward amount in various addiction studies.  I realize this is a very complicated question but I should be able to get good enough results to measure puff volume using a differential pressure sensor and a orifice plate.

Comment: @user31782 I'm not sure about off topic as this is looks like a fluid dynamics question. I did remove the question in chemistry as that wasn't the right place for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the reference [Physical, Chemical, and Biologic Properties of Tobacco, Cigarette Smoke, and other Tobacco Products](http://legacy.library.ucsf.edu/documentStore/c/c/e/cce40e00/Scce40e00.pdf).

The reference considers 500mg of cigarette smoke, and says it is 478mg gas phase and 22mg liquid phase.  The gas phase contains 350mg air, 50mg water vapor, 50mg carbon dioxide and 20mg carbon monoxide.  The liquid phase contains 1.3mg nicotine, 3.7mg water and the rest (17mg) of the liquid phase is categorized as "tar".  The article futher explains what is in the "tar".